# replace a list of words with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of words `list_words =["cat","dog","animals"]`

And i have a `text = "I have a lot of animals a cat and a dog"`

I want a regex code that is able to add a comma at the end of every word before any word in the list given.

I want my text to be like that: `text = "I have a lot of, animals a, cat and a, dog"`

My code so far:

```
import re
list_words = ["cat", "dog", "animals","adam"]
text = "I have a lot of animals,       cat and a     dog"

for word in list_words:
    if word in text:
        word = re.search(r" (\s*{})".format(word), text).group(1)
        text = text.replace(f" {word}", f", {word}")
print(text)
```

But i have 2 issues here:

1: if i have a text like this : `text= I have a lot of animals cat and a  dogy`

it turns it into : `text= I have a lot of, animals, cat and a,  dogy`

which is not the result wanted, i wanted to replace only the word itself not with

addition like dogy

2: if i have a text like this: `text= I have a lot of animals, cat and a  dogy`

it still add another comma which is not what i want

Comment: Hint: Use a positive lookahead that matches any of the words in the list.

Comment: Do you know how to split the string? Do you know how to iterate over the list?

Comment: @Barmar i did try and got this: (?=cat), but don't know how to get the word just  before it

Comment: @Joffan yes i know but i want a regex solution not with split

Comment: `\w(?=\s+ cat)` will match the last character of the word before it

Comment: @Barmar (\s*)(cat) replace it with , \2 get the job done for me, thank you

Comment: Don't forget to match word boundaries. Otherwise this will replace `recapture` with `re, capture`

Comment: @Barmar u mean like that: r'(\s*)(cat)?

Comment: `\s*` will match zero spaces. Use `\s+` to match at least one space.

Comment: But also use `cat\b` so it won't match `catsup`

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your time, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Edit the question and show what you tried. Then we can vote on whether to reopen it.

Comment: @Barmar i did please take a look at it

Comment: You still don't use `\b` to make it match whole words. Why not?

Comment: And also use `re.sub()` so it only replaces the match, not similar strings elsewhere.

Comment: `text = re.sub(rf'\s+{word}\b', r', \1', text)`

Comment: @Barmar i get this error when i try your method : TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Was that before I fixed the typo of `text.replace` with `re.sub`?

Comment: @Barmar yes, and when i use re.sub (exactly your code) i get this error: raise s.error("invalid group reference %d" % index, pos)
re.error: invalid group reference 1 at position 3

Comment: I forrgot the parenthese around the capture group. Add them.

Comment: Or use `\0` to replace the whole match.

Comment: @Barmar thanks it's working now, one thing left is how to not add a comma if there is already a one

Comment: Use a negative lookbehind. `(?!<,)`

Comment: Do you mean the expected output for the string in your code is `I have a lot of, animals,       cat and a,     dog`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, but if there is already a comma before any word on the list it gonna add another one which i don't want to

Comment: It is fine, I posted a [solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67728840/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
,*(\s*\b(?:cat|dog|animals|adam))\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QoQ7Ae/1/). *Details*:

- `,*` - zero or more commas
- `(\s*\b(?:cat|dog|animals|adam))` - Group 1:

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `(?:cat|dog|animals|adam)` - one of the words
- `\b` - word boundary

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/bSuvxV):

```py
import re
list_words = ["cat", "dog", "animals", "adam"]
text = "I have a lot of animals,       cat and a     dog"
pattern = r",*(\s*\b(?:{}))\b".format("|".join(list_words))
print( re.sub(pattern, r",\1", text) )
# => I have a lot of, animals,       cat and a,     dog
```

Comment: it's working finally, i did use this: r"[,.]*(\s*\b(?:{}))\b".format("|".join(list_words)) to match also dots if there is any, thanks Wiktor

Answer (score 1):

All words get a comma:

```py
import re

list_words = ["cat", "dog", "animals"]
text = "I have a lot of animals a cat and a dog"

for word in list_words:
    word = re.search(r" (\s*{}) ".format(word), text)
    text = text.replace(f" {word}", f", {word}")
```

Comment: it's not working in this case: I have a lot of animals a  (a lot of spaces)  cat and a dog

Comment: Then search via regex for any number of spaces and return the text, you can replace that afterwards

Comment: Something like that

`word = re.search(r" (\s*{})".format(word), text).group(1)`

Comment: it's working thank you, one more thing, if i have already a comma before the word i don't want it to be added, like this :text = "I have a lot of animals a, cat and a dog"

Comment: Editing the answer, try to understand it at least btw

Comment: but your code isn't working! did you try it first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232975/discussion-between-raumschifffan-and-chikabala).

Answer (score 0):

Go with a simpler method.

```
list_words =["cat","dog","animals"]
text = "I have a lot of animals a cat and a dog"
test_list_words=[]
for new in text.split(" "):
        if new in list_words:
                new=new+","
                test_list_words.append(new)
        else:
                test_list_words.append(new)
print(' '.join(test_list_words))
```

Comment: same issue if i have a lot of spaces before the words in the list it won't give me the result wanted